# Django multiple database foreign keys

Tags: django, postgresql, multiple-databases

I am trying to implement multiple database support for my django (version 1.11) app. For that purpose I have included in my `settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'labrin_dbase',
        'USER': 'labrin_admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'ndzwwZHv63STuvAF?C_$L@j@*@epZXaX',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    },
    'comment': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'labrin_dbase_comments',
        'USER': 'labrin_admin_comments',
        'PASSWORD': 'adzwaTHv63STuvAF!C_$L@j@*@epZXaY',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5433',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'labrin_task.comment_router.CommentRouter',
]
```

And my database router is configured as below:

```
class CommentRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.db_table == 'todo_comment':
            return 'comment'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.db_table == 'todo_comment':
            return 'comment'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if model_name == 'comment':
            return db == 'comment'
        return None
```

Models in my "todo" `app`(which is only app in project):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

UserModel = get_user_model()


class Todo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Comment(models.Model):
    todo = models.ForeignKey(Todo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ShareTodo(models.Model):
    todo = models.ForeignKey(Todo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    with_user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment_allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When I remove `comment` database and `DATABASE_ROUTERS` from `settings.py`, my app is working normally. After adding mentioned to `settings.py`, my app returns an error when I create `Comment` object. The error says:

`Exception inside application: insert or update on table "todo_comment" violates foreign key constraint "todo_comment_author_id_bb272a3e_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (author_id)=(1) is not present in table "auth_user".` What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** I am starting two postgres servers as separate docker containers and after running containers, I run `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py migrate --database=comment` for making all migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but cross-database relations are not possible to recreate in Django. You can find full explanation in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/multi-db/#cross-database-relations).

Furthermore, you cannot even do cross-database relations in PostgreSQL so even trying to hack it or to achieve it outside of Django won't be possible. Maybe for other database engines it is possible, you can do your own research.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems that I missed the part of django documentation that you mentioned. Can you suggest possible workarounds or other options to this problem?